# Okhttp3.CertificatePinner error in android 4 just in release APK

Tags: release, okhttp, android-4.4-kitkat

Just in Release version and on belowe android5 app crashed on the line below:

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
```

the error is:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
    at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.withCertificateChainCleaner(CertificatePinner.java:231)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:238)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
```

Comment: what version of okhttp are you using?
did you include the  proguard rules?

Comment: I downgrade it to 3.12.1 and disable the minifyenabled.

Comment: have you tried: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro

Comment: No. how should i use it?

Comment: add it to your proguard